# Determination of order of group element

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, finite-groups, abelian-groups

Let $G:=\frac{\mathbb{Z}_{3^{15}}\times \mathbb{Z}_{3^{12}}}{\langle (3^7.2, 0)\rangle}$. The order of $G$ is $3^{19}$. Consider
$\chi:=(3^4.7, 0)+K$ where $K=\langle (3^7.2, 0)\rangle$. To find the order of $\chi$.

I have attempted the solution in the following way. Please guide me if this is correct. Since
$\chi\in G$, by Lagrange's theorem, order of $\chi$ is $3^r$ for some $r>0$. Now
$|3^4.7|=3^{11}$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{3^{15}}$. Therefore
$$3^{11}(3^4.7, 0)=(3^{15}.7, 0)=(0,0).$$
On the other hand, $3^8(3^7.2, 0)=(0,0)$. Thus
$$3^{11}(3^4.7, 0)=(0,0)=3^8(3^7.2, 0)\in K$$
which shows $3^{11}((3^7.7, 0)+K)=K$ i.e. desired order of $\chi$ is $3^{11}$.

Is this correct? Please suggest. Thanks in advance.

**Update1**: I believe I have made mistake in my calculation. Since
$$3^3(3^4.7, 0)=(3^7.7, 0)=2^{-1}.7(3^7.2, 0)\in K$$
therefore $3^3$ is the smallest positive integer for which $3^3(3^4.7,0)\in K$. Thus desired order is $3^3$. Is it correct?